# Python changing list into a word

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I had a problem in python for a couple of days and cant seem to fix it.
How can I just simply change this code below:

```
['a'], ['b'], ['c']
to this :
['abc']
```

thanks !

Comment: Is your input a `tuple`? So `start = ['a'], ['b'], ['c']`

Comment: `''.join(c for sublist in (['a'], ['b'], ['c']) for c in sublist)`

Comment: yea my program is pretty simple ... codedletters = ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] so i take all the letters in codedletters and make a word...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
codedletters = ['a'], ['b'], ['c']
answer = [''.join([x[0] for x in codedletters])]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['abc']
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what your problem is. Are you attempting to concatenate the strings?  If so, I would use itertools/chain:

```
from itertools import chain
print [''.join(chain(['a'], ['b'], ['c']))]
```